# Macro with optional paramaters that checks for whether an optional paramater is defined?

Tags: elisp, elisp-macros

Due to my lazy nature, I made something like this:

```
(defmacro iλ (x)
  `(lambda () (interactive) ,x))

(defmacro iλd (x y)
     `(lambda () ,x (interactive) ,y))

(global-set-key (kbd "<f8>") (iλ (message "hello lambdas")))
(global-set-key (kbd "<f7>") (iλd "Func Docu" (message "hello lambda with docus")))
```

Due to my lazy nature, I would like to merge these two but it's 10:16pm in the evening and I can't seem to figure it out. I would like something like this (Pseudo code follows):

```
 (defmacro iλ (x &optional y)   ;y is optional parameter:
  if x & y are defined:
  `(lambda () ,x (interactive) ,y))
  else if only x is defined:  
  `(lambda () (interactive) ,y)
  )
```

Can this be done, if so how?

**[edit solution]**
As per Malabarba's answer below, I now use the clever bit of code:

```
(defmacro iλ (x &rest y) 
    (if (and (stringp x) y) 
        `(lambda () ,x (interactive) ,@y) 
      `(lambda () (interactive) ,x ,@y)))
;Example usage:
(global-set-key (kbd "<f8>") (iλ "A message that prints a hello" (message "hello 2")))
(global-set-key (kbd "<f9>") (iλ  (message "hello 1")))
```

Comment: In other words you want to treat any parameter whose name begins with an ampersand as if it was optional? This is doable, in a sense, but there are lots of problems associated with it: what about keywords? What about other useful syntax such as `&rest`? What if you then write `(iλ x &x)`?

Comment: Oh @wvxvw, I was confused X-D. I meant `(x &optional y)`  thank you for pointing this out.

Comment: I updated question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's what you're trying to do

```
(defmacro iλ (x &optional y) 
  (if (and (stringp x) y) 
      `(lambda () ,x (interactive) ,y)) 
    `(lambda () (interactive) ,x ,y)))
```

And, if you're taking suggestions, here's what I recommend. It should allow you to use any number of forms.

```
(defmacro iλ (x &rest y) 
  (if (and (stringp x) y) 
      `(lambda () ,x (interactive) ,@y)
    `(lambda () (interactive) ,x ,@y)))
```

As @Stefan suggests, if you're on Emacs 25 you can do:

```
(defmacro iλ (&rest body)
  (let ((x (macroexp-parse-body body)))
    `(lambda () ,@(car x) (interactive)
       ,@(cdr x))))
```

Comment: With Emacs-25, I'd do `(defmacro iλ (&rest body) (let ((x (macroexp-parse-body body))) `(lambda () ,@(car x) (interactive) ,@(cdr x))))`.

Comment: @Stefan `macroexp-parse-body` is a good suggestion, but in this particular case a string such as `(iλ "return-value")` would be confused with a docstring and the resulting lambda would always return `nil`.

Comment: `macroexp-parse-body` would treat such a lone string as the body, not as the docstring.  If you find it doesn't in your case, then please report it as a bug.

Comment: @Stefan You're right, I was confused.

Comment: Awesome. I'll use the 2nd version for now, maybe the E25 version in the future.  I think there is a typo thou, the 2nd line has one too many ')' bracket. Removing it makes it work for me. I.e:   (defmacro iλlam (x &rest y) 
    (if (and (stringp x) y) 
        `(lambda () ,x (interactive) ,@y) 
      `(lambda () (interactive) ,x ,@y)))

Comment: @LeoUfimtsev Fixed, thanks for noting.

Comment: @Malabarba while at it, do you think you could take a look at this question also? http://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/10322/5350  (if you have time).